# Count number of occurrences of a specific regex on multiple files

Tags: bash

I am trying to write up a bash script to count the number of times a specific pattern matches on a list of files.

I've googled for solutions but I've only found solutions for single files.

I know I can use `egrep -o PATTERN file`, but how do I generalize to a list of files and out the sum at the end?

EDIT: Adding the script I am trying to write:

```
#! /bin/bash

egrep -o -c "\s*assert.*;" $1 | awk -F: '{sum+=$2} END{print sum}'
```

Running egrep directly on the command line works fine, but within a bash script it doesn't. Do I have to specially protect the RegEx?

Comment: I'm afraid this requirement is special enough that you'll have to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `grep -c` to count the matches within each file, and then use `awk` at the end to sum up the counts, e.g.:

```
grep -c PATTERN * | awk -F: '{sum+=$2} END{print sum}'
```

Comment: I've never used `awk`, seems a nifty little thing there. I want to put this on a bash script, but it doesn't work, it always returns `0`. Look at the script above.

Comment: @TiagoVeloso: What does `grep -c PATTERN *` print out? It should be `file:count`, one line per input file.

Comment: It is working like that, the problem only occurs when I put the command on a script file.

Comment: @TiagoVeloso: What if you remove the `| awk -F: '{sum+=$2} END{print sum}'` from the script? Does it print out the file names you expect and the counts?

Comment: I know the problem. The problem is that `$1` is only expanded to one file instead of the all the files. Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: Use `"$@"` instead of `$*` (make sure you include the double quotes) -- that properly protects any files with whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -o <pattern> file1 [file2 .. | *] |
    uniq -c
```

If you want the total only:

```
grep -o <pattern> file1 [file2 .. | *] | wc -l
```

Edit: The sort seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has a problem in that `grep` will count as 1 even though the PATTERN may appear more than once on a line.  Besides, one command does the job

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0777";FS="PATTERN"} { print NF-1 } ' file
```